# Direct OpenGL ES 2.0 drawing over Cocos2d drawing

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I have got a layer. It has got the children with specific 'z' value.
e.g.

- Child_1 z==-10.0f (CCSprite)
- Child_2 z==-5.0f  (My custom node)
- Child_3 z==-1.0f  (CCSprite)

My custom node (Child_2) has the direct Opengl es invocation inside the 'draw' method  to draw textures via shaders.

The issue I stick with:

if I add children in such steps everything is OK:

```
[self addChild:Child_1 z:-10.0f tag:1];
[self addChild:Child_2 z:-5.0f tag:2];
[self addChild:Child_3 z:-1.0f tag:3];
```

if I add them in a such way:

```
[self addChild:Child_1 z:-10.0f tag:1];
[self addChild:Child_3 z:-1.0f tag:3];
[self addChild:Child_2 z:-5.0f tag:2];
```

Child_3 is not visible but must be.

How to use opengl es draw invocation for the proper drawing behaviour?

PS Here is code

```
[hm2 use];
glVertexAttribPointer ( 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vVertices2 );
glEnableVertexAttribArray ( 0 );
glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3 );
```

Comment: Post your custom GL drawing code. I'm guessing you don't correctly reset the GL states or the code causes OpenGL errors which causes any follow-up drawing code to fail as well. Be sure to use only the ccDraw* methods instead of gl* methods whenever there is a ccDraw* counterpart, otherwise cocos2d drawing may be messed up.

Comment: There are not any fail. Yes, I use glDrawArrays.

Comment: I will answer in 6 hours because I am not allowed by site to do it now

Answer (score 0):

**LearnCocos2D**, thank you! I have discovered ccDraw* and found that there no gl* with z value. My mistake was that I used glDrawArrays with z-value.
Why did I? Because I wanted two different textures one of which overlaps another but both of them should be over Child_1 and behind Child_3.
To avoid the issue I stuck with glDrawArrays shouldn't be with z-value.

In order to avoid that issue and to make textures with different depth inside Child_2 I guess that solution is to create new two nodes and then add them as a children to Child_2.

eg

```
@implementation Child_2

...

-(id) init
{
[self addChild:Child_2_1 z:-1.0f tag:0];
[self addChild:Child_2_2 z:-2.0f tag:1];
```

Good luck!